# Can't seem to make an ajax work inside another

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to use ajax inside an ajax but it shows me an error on the success of the second ajax.

I need to identify if the user has permission to pay the bail before recording the bail in the database.

Is says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. In the code I put a comment on the line of the error.

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php?route=bail/bail_authorize",
    data: {
        data_send       : data_send,
        action          : 'authorization',
        username        : result['value'][0],
        password        : result['value'][1],
    },
    dataType: "html",
    error: function(){
        swal({  
            text: "no se pudo autorizar", 
            timer: 5000, 
            icon: "error",
            type: "error" 
        });
    },
    success: function(data){
        if(data=="1"){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?route=bail/bail_generate",
                data: {
                    data_send   : data_send,
                    username    : result['value'][0],
                    password    : result['value'][1],
                },
                dataType: "html",
                error: function(){
                    swal({  
                        text: "no se pudo generar la garantia", 
                        timer: 5000, 
                        icon: "error",
                        type: "error" 
                    });
                }
                success: function(data){//this line shows error
                    if(data=="1"){
                        swal({
                            type: 'success',
                            title: 'Garantias almacenadas de forma exitosa',
                            showConfirmButton: false,
                            timer: 1500
                        });
                        window.location.href('index.php?route=bail/bail');
                    }
                    else{
                        swal({
                            type: 'error',
                            title: 'Oops...',
                            text: 'Las garantias no se pudieron almacenar',
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else{
            swal({
                type: 'error',
                title: 'Oops...',
                text: 'Compruebe user y password!',
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Anyone knows what is it about? I undestood I coud use ajz inside ajax in this way.

Comment: `but it shows me an error` `Anyone knows what is it about?` What error?

Comment: Thanks for the observation. I have edited the text to put the error

Comment: You are missing a comma after the `error` callback and `success` callback

Comment: Why did you tag this with php?  And HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma between the error callback and success callback.

```
error: function(){
  ...
}, /* Missing here */
success: function(){
  ...
}
```

Comment: It was the comma. Feeling like a noob

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if you added `jQuery` in you `index.html` (or whatever the case may be) as a first step.

Adding the thrown error to your question would help alot in debugging.

Comment: I have edited the text to include the error. Before the second ajax everything was fine

Comment: You are missing a comma between the error callback and success callback.